# httpErrors config in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

There is a httpErrors config in my web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Replace" />
```

it does not show detail of script error in local because of existingResponse="Replace".
I want to see detail of script error in local and in client I want to show cusstom error page

Comment: Seems that `httErrors` is a typo. httpErrors?

Answer (score 0):

Check the coustomError tag in web.config file.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
</customErrors>
```

Set the mode to "RemoteOnly".

Comment: If you have configured custom error pages in your application using <customErrors/> tag, then, try by removing the <httpErrors/> tag from your web.config file.